# SPFX - React - list / listItem/ page is undefined in this.context.pageContext

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, react

I am creating SPFX web part with React.

In which I am trying to get the current page ID on which webpart is added. I was trying to check if I can get it directly from the page context.

I am getting page context using `this.context.pageContext` but I noticed some of the properties are undefined.

like `this.context.pageContext.list`, `this.context.pageContext.listItem`, `this.context.pageContext.page` these are undefined.

Could any one please tell me the reason behind this. OR please guide me on how to get the ID of the page on which web part is added.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as it might be useful for someone else.

I figured that these properties are undefined while working/debugging on **workbench**.

But when we package and deploye this web part on particulat page, we can access these properties.

Cheers :)